# Database Relational Homework help

Tags: database, relational

The Problem "Consider a relation R with five attributes ABCDE. You are given the following dependancies

1. A->B
2. BC->E
3. ED->A

List all the keys for R.

The teacher gave us the keys, Which are ACD,BCD,CDE

And we need to show the work to get to them.

<del>The First two I solved.</del>

<del>For BCD, the transitive of 2 with 3 to get (BC->E)D->A => BCD->A.</del>
<del>and for ACD id the the transitive of 1 with 4 (BCD), to get (A->B)CD->A => ACD->A</del>

<del>But I can't figure out how to get CDE.</del>

So it seems I did it wrong, after googling I found this answer

1. methodology to find keys: 
   consider attribute sets α containing: a. the determinant attributes of F (i.e. A, BC, 
   ED) and b. the attributes NOT contained in the determined ones (i.e. C,D). Then 
   do the attribute closure  algorithm:
   if α+ superset R then α -> R
   Three keys: CDE, ACD, BCD
   [Source](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/profs/Michalis.Vazirgiannis/lab_slides/Lab_3_solutions.pdf)

From what I can tell, since C,D are not on the left side of the dependencies. The keys are left sides with CD pre-appended to them. Can anyone explain this to me in better detail as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get they **keys**, you start with **one of the dependencies** and using inference to extend the set.

Let me have a go with simple English, you can find formal definition the net easily.

e.g. start with 3).

```
ED -> A
```

(knowing E and D, I know A)

```
ED ->AB
```

(knowing E and D, I know A, by knowing A, I know B as well)

```
ED->AB
```

Still, C cannot be known, and I have used all the rules now except BC->E,
So I add C to the left hand side, i.e.

```
CDE ->AB
```

so, **by knowing C,D and E**, you will know **A** and **B** as well,
Hence **CDE is a key for your relation ABCDE**. You repeat the same process, starting with other rules until exhausted.

Comment: you cannot just say if attributes are on the left handside or not to determine whether its a possible key.

Comment: So is this a correct way to do the next possible key?
BC->E, knowing E, and ED->A, I get BCD->AE?

Comment: for the last one i did A->B, Since BC->E, I know B, so AC->EB,, since D can't be known I added it the left side to get ACD->EB

Comment: yes, you got the idea I think. Its a iterative process that until all dependencies are exhausted. So its not easy working out large examples by hand, but its very efficient with computers.